# Having trouble installing gem devise for my Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

after adding gem 'devise' to my gem file and running $bundle install, i get the following:

```
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/util.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.


An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

This is what was returned by the terminal, tried install bcrypt separately, but it just wont work.

Thank you in advance !

```
Anonyos-iMac:omrails manny$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using multi_json (1.7.7) 
Using activesupport (3.2.12) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.12) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.12) 
Using mime-types (1.23) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.14) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.12) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activerecord (3.2.12) 
Using activeresource (3.2.12) 
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/util.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include`enter code here`
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:14:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/manny/.bundler/tmp/1023/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/manny/.bundler/tmp/1023/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Have you checked the mkmf.log as suggested in the error message ?

Comment: You're using a Mac? That's you answer `You have to install development tools first.`

Comment: Thing is called "command line tools" they are bundled with xcode but can get them separately somewhere on apple website.

Comment: The problem at the moment is that developer pages on apple are down due to a hack couple days ago so you probably need to google it out or go for Xcode, 4gb download in app store...

Comment: yeah, I'm on mac running mountain lion, i already have xcode installed, ill look into development tools

Comment: Yes, so if you have Xcode, google how to install "command line tools", you need to go somewhere in the menu and just click install.